# Copy external file or fallback to internal file with WiX

Tags: wix, wix3.8

As the title says, I want to install an external file:

```
<Component>
    <File Source="Application.exe.config" Compressed="no" />
</Component>
```

and–if the external file is not available–install the default, internal file:

```
<Component>
    <File Source="Application.exe.default.config" Name="Application.exe.config" />
</Component>
```

So that is guaranteed, that there is always a file installed.
How can I achieve that?

To clarify: By external I do NOT mean a CopyFile-Element. Instead I am talking about a normal WiX-File (as seen in the first Snippet) that is simply not compressed into a cab.

Comment: what do you mean by an external file?

Comment: @Isaiah4110 as seen in my code snippets: a file that is not embedded in the msi but delivered separately.

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippet shows the file in the MSI, not external, that's the confusion. If it's external it's not in the WiX or the MSI, you would copy it using a WiX CopyFile element.

I'd be tempted to use a file search to see if the file is present and store that resulting property with the WiX remember property pattern. Make your file component transitive and conditioned on "NOT FILEFOUND", for example, so it doesn't get installed if the external file is found. Then you just need the external file copied if FILEFOUND is set. For this, I would add another transitive component containing only a registry entry (it must contain something) with condition FILEFOUND. Put the WiX CopyFile in this component so it runs when FILEFOUND is set. I think that would do it without writing any code.

Comment: I updated the question for clarification. Could you please add a bit of code? I haven't used Conditions yet and it sounds like this might work for me. FileSearch and transitive are both useful hints.

Comment: Do a search on -WiX tutorial- and take it from there. For an external file copy from next to the MSI file, look for a WiX CopyFile example that has SourceDir as the source location. Also look at the -From MSI to WiX- blog entries.

Comment: What's the advantage in using CopyFile vs a File with attribute Compressed="no"?

Comment: Compressed=no means the file is still part of the MSI, so it's not truly external, just installed by the MSI from a file rather than extracted from a CAB file. CopyFile is primarily for your situation in which you don't wsnt Windows Installer registering it, knowing its file hash, replacing it with the original on a repair if you replace it etc.